# Derivatives of a fraction function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, fractions

An example of a fraction function is:
$$y= \frac{-8x}{(x^2 + 3)^2}$$
The [quotient rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule) says that if the function one wishes to differentiate, $f(x)$, can be written as:
$$h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$
Then the derivative is (according to what I learned):
$$h'(x) = \frac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{(g(x))^2}$$

Then I think the procedure is the following:

\begin{align}
y' & = \frac{24(x^2 - 1)}{((x^2+3)^2)^2}\\
& = \frac{24(x^2 - 1)}{(x^2+3)^4}\\
\end{align}

However, the solution is...
$$y'= \frac{24(x^2 - 1)}{(x^2+3)^3}$$

> - What are my mistakes?
> - What is the correct way to derivate fractions?

Comment: Although this mistake did not cause any problem note that $(x^2)^y\not =x^{2^y}$. It is $x^{2y}$.

Comment: Oh, well I meant the second one. What does it mean the first one? I will edit my question.

Comment: As an example: let $a=2$ $b=3$. Then $x^{a^b}=x^{2^3}=x^8$ whereas $x^{ab}=x^{2\cdot3}=x^6$.

Comment: @zoli Oh right! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second step (after writing down the quotient rule) should be:
$$ y' = \frac{-8(x^2+3)^2+8x \cdot 2 \cdot 2x(x^2+3)}{((x^2+3)^2)^2}, $$
and then an $x^2+3$ cancels off and gives you the correct answer:
$$  \frac{-8(x^2+3)^2+8x \cdot 2 \cdot 2x(x^2+3)}{((x^2+3)^2)^2} = \frac{-8(x^2+3)+32x^2}{(x^2+3)^3} = \frac{24(x^2-1)}{(x^2+3)^3}. $$

Comment: The derivative of $f(x) = -8x$ is $f'(x) = -8$.  Or perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: No, don't worry, that's just my crap algebra again...

Answer (score 1):

Hint #1: If you write your fraction as
$$HIGH/LOW,$$
then the derivative for the quotient is "given" by the **mnemonic**
$$\frac{LOW\cdot{d(HIGH)} - HIGH \cdot{d(LOW)}}{(LOW)^2}.$$

Hint #2: $d(HIGH) = -8$

Hint #3: $d(LOW) = 2(x^2 + 3)(2x) = 4x(x^2 + 3)$

Can you take it from here?